# SPEED UP Django Form to Upload large (500k obs) CSV file to MySQL DB

Tags: python, mysql, django, csv

The Django table is approximately 430,000 obs and 230mb file;\
and comes from a flat CSV file outlined by details below in\
MODELS.PY. I have considered using chunks for the CSV Reader but I think the Processor\
function I have that populates the MySQL table is my hangup; it takes 20 hours+\
HOW CAN I SPEED THIS UP??

```
class MastTable(models.Model):
    evidence = models.ForeignKey(Evidence, blank=False)
    var2 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    var3 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    var4 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    var5 = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    var6 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    var7 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    var8 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    var9 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    var10 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    var11 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    var12 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    var13 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    var14 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    var15 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    var16 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    var17 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    var18 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    var19 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    var20 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    var21 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    var22 = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    var23 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    var24 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    var25 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    var26 = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This helper function will create a reader object for the CSV\
and also decode any funky codecs in the file before MySQL upload

```
def unicode_csv_reader(utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'ISO-8859-1') for cell in row]
```

A function in a UTILS.PY File will then access a DB table (named 'extract_properties') which\
contains the file header to identify which processor function to go to\
the processor function will look like this, below

```
def processor_table(extract_properties):  #Process the table into MySQL
    evidence_obj, created = Evidence.objects.get_or_create(case=case_obj, 
    evidence_number=extract_properties['evidence_number']) #This retrieves the Primary Key
    reader = unicode_csv_reader(extract_properties['uploaded_file'],dialect='pipes') #CSVfunction  
    for idx, row in enumerate(reader):
        if idx <= (extract_properties['header_row_num'])+3: #Header is not always 1st row of file
            pass
        else:
            try:
                obj, created = MastTable.objects.create( #I was originally using 'get_or_create'
                    evidence=evidence_obj,
                    var2=row[0],
                    var3=row[1],
                    var4=row[2],
                    var5=row[3],
                    var6=date_convert(row[4],row[5]), #funct using 'dateutil.parser.parse'
                    var7=date_convert(row[6],row[7]),
                    var8=date_convert(row[8],row[9]),
                    var9=date_convert(row[10],row[11]),
                    var10=date_convert(row[12],row[13]),
                    var11=date_convert(row[14],row[15]),
                    var12=date_convert(row[16],row[17]),
                    var13=date_convert(row[18],row[19]),
                    var14=row[20],
                    var15=row[21],
                    var16=row[22],
                    var17=row[23],
                    var18=row[24],
                    var19=row[25],
                    var20=row[26],
                    var21=row[27],
                    var22=row[28],
                    var23=date_convert(row[29],row[30]),
                    var24=date_convert(row[31],row[32]),
                    var25=date_convert(row[33],row[34]),
                    var26=date_convert(row[35],row[36]),)
            except Exception as e:  #This logs any exceptions to a custom DB table
                print "Error",e
                print "row",row
                print "idx:",idx
                SystemExceptionLog.objects.get_or_create(indexrow=idx, errormsg=e.args[0],     
                timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(),   
                uploadedfile=extract_properties['uploaded_file'])
                continue
    return True
```

Finally the VIEWS.PY Form below to accept file and Call the processor above to populate DB
Checks for valid form data and passes any files to the file handler if valid

```
def upload_file(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            for _file in request.FILES.getlist('file'): 
                extract_properties = get_file_properties(_file) 
                if extract_properties:
                    for property in extract_properties: #File is found and processor kicked off 
                        print "starting parser"
                        try:
                            property['evidence_number'] = request.POST.get('evidence_number')
                            result = process_extract(property)
                            if result is None:
                                print 'Unable to get determine extract properties!'
                        except Exception as e:
                            print "!!!!!!!"
                            print "Error, could not upload", e
                            pass
                 else:
                    print 'Unable to identify file uploaded!' 
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
        print form
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('nettop/upload_file.html',  # The web frontend Page for Upload
                              {'form': form},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most basic and effective optimization in Django is to reduce the number of queries to the database. That's true for 100 queries, and that's most certainly true for 500.000 queries.

Instead of using `MastTable.objects.create()`, you should construct a list of unsaved model instances, and use `MastTable.objects.bulk_create(list_of_models)` to create them all in as few round-trips to the database as possible. This should speed it up tremendously.

If you're using MySQL, you can increase the `max_allowed_packet` setting to allow for larger batches. Its default of 1MB is quite low. PostGRESQL has no hardcoded limit. If you're still running into performance issues, you can switch to [raw SQL statements](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly). Creating 500.000 python objects can be a bit of an overhead. In one of my recent tests, executing the exact same query with `connection.cursor` was about 20% faster.

It can be a good idea to leave the actual processing of the file to a background process using e.g. Celery, or using a `StreamingHttpResponse` to provide feedback during the process.

Answer (score 0):

Does this csv file contains invalid rows?  I mean do you really need this line?

```
except Exception as e:  #This logs any exceptions to a custom DB table
```

If there is no such errors thrown then you should use `bulk_create()` instead of just `create()`.

Also I suggest to execute import in the single transaction.  It is a **HUGE** speed booster:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    processor_table(extract_properties)
```

Comment: The Exception reporting is because the data sourced can be dynamic. I had some issues with funky codecs, prior. I have tried using bulk_create. I'm a little uncertain but interested in the 'transaction.atomic()'. Is this similar to just using MySQL interface and skipping Django ORM altogether?(a considered alternative for me)

Comment: Skipping Django ORM and using transactions are not alternatives - you can (and, imho, should) do both.  Try `transaction.atomic()` at first, it is simple and will increase speed of your application to an order of magnitude. After that switch to plain SQL to get additional speed increase.